# Access denied for s3 bucket for terraform backend

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform-provider-aws

My terraform code is as below:

```
# PROVIDERS
provider "aws" {
  profile = var.aws_profile
  region  = var.region
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 1.0.4"
    }
  }
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform-backend-20200102"
    key    = "test.tfstate"
  }
}
# DATA

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

data "template_file" "public_cidrsubnet" {
  count    = var.subnet_count
  template = "$${cidrsubnet(vpc_cidr,8,current_count)}"
  vars = {
    vpc_cidr      = var.network_address_space
    current_count = count.index
  }
}

# RESOURCES
module "vpc" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  name            = var.name
  version         = "2.62.0"
  cidr            = var.network_address_space
  azs             = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, var.subnet_count)
  public_subnets  = []
  private_subnets = data.template_file.public_cidrsubnet[*].rendered
  tags            = local.common_tags
}
```

However, when I run terraform init, it gives me an error.

```
$ terraform.exe init -reconfigure
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...
region
  AWS region of the S3 Bucket and DynamoDB Table (if used).

  Enter a value: ap-southeast-2


Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Error refreshing state: AccessDenied: Access Denied
        status code: 403, request id: A2EB50094A12E22F, host id: JFwXo11eiAW3N0JL1Yoi/i1k03aqzSIwj34NOgMT/ScgmBEC/nncjsK/GKik0SFIT6Ym8Mr/j6U=



/vpc_create
$ aws s3 ls --profile=tcp-aws-sandbox-31
2020-11-02 23:05:48 terraform-backend-20200102
```

Do note that I can list my bucket from ***aws s3 ls*** command then why does terraform has any issue!?

**P.S:** I am trying to go to the local state file hence commented out the backend block, but it is still giving me an error, please assist.

```
# terraform {
#   backend "s3" {
#     bucket = "terraform-backend-20200102"
#     key    = "test.tfstate"
#   }
# }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ran **aws configure** and then it worked.
For some reason it was taking the wrong account even though, I set the correct *aws profile* in **~.aws/credentials** file.

The way I realized it was using the wrong account was when I ran **terraform apply** *after* **export TF_LOG=DEBUG**

Comment: Using that environment variable helped me debug the issue. It turns out that I was getting an "Access denied error" when trying to create a bucket because of a duplicate name error while creating the S3 bucket

Comment: The TF_LOG=DEBUG saved my life. For me, turned out it is picking the wrong credentials from env vars instead of from the credentials file. All I had to do then was unset the vars.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. It was because the AWS CLI profile that I was using was different from the one I specified in the provider section. Once I corrected this, and make sure that AWS CLI user profile matches the one in the terraform provider section, the error went away and the statefile was saved to my s3 bucket.

Comment: the profile in AWS CLI needs to be authorized. If it is authorized, even if it doesn't match the profile in terraform code, the code will still work. I guess the simpliest solution is just make sure these 2 profiles match.